# Where is Couchbase Sync Gateway AdminUI?

Tags: couchbase

I have already set `"adminUI": "0.0.0.0:4985/_admin/"` in my config. I still get `404 page not found` when going to the endpoint (e.g. `http://<host IP>:4985/_admin/`).

This is the description of the config line `adminUI` from http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/1.2/develop/guides/sync-gateway/configuring-sync-gateway/config-properties/index.html

> URL of the Sync Gateway Admin Console HTML page. The default is the bundled Sync Gateway Admin Console at localhost:4985/_admin/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got this hint from https://github.com/couchbase/sync_gateway/blob/aba088a902b162bcaed745510f4d012b8908a303/rest/config.go#L64

`` AdminUI  *string  `json:",omitempty"` // Path to Admin HTML page, if omitted uses bundled HTML ``

I omitted the line `"adminUI": "0.0.0.0:4985/_admin/"` from the config file to get the bundled Couchbase Sync Gateway Admin UI HTML page.

Comment: Note, the trailing slash is very important: http://localhost:4985/_admin/ works for me, but https://localhost:4985/_admin does not